# How to take int from json and parse it as bool in dart?

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, dart, orm

I have my model as follows:

```
class Abc extends Model {
  int playful;

  Abc({this.playful}) : super(id);

  Abc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : this(playful: json['playful']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['playful'] = this.playful;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I am getting integer value `playful` (it is either 1 or 0) from `json` but I want to use it as a `boolean` in my app (receive as `bool` in app but send as `int` in database). How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Abc extends Model {
  bool playful;

  Abc({this.playful}) : super(id);

  Abc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : this(playful: json['playful'] == 1);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['playful'] = this.playful ? 1 : 0;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Perfectly described. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Dart doesn't have any function or method for parsing booleans. So I would create a private function in this class which would return boolean for given integer.

```
bool parseBool(int integer) {
  return integer == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more automated and up to date method on how to cope with it using [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation), [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) & [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) packages. It is useful, when you have more complex classes to (de)serialize.

Remember to place these packages in your project **pubspec.yaml** file under correct dependencies and create **abc.g.dart** as a sibling file before running `dart run build_runner build` in terminal.

And here's the code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'abc.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Abc {
  Abc({required this.playful});

  factory Abc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AbcFromJson(json);

  @JsonKey(toJson: _toJson, fromJson: _fromJson)
  bool playful;
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AbcToJson(this);

  static int _toJson(bool value) {
    if (value == true) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  static bool _fromJson(int value) {
    if (value == 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It also works for other types, eg. String to bool. Hope this helps someone, greetings.